# How can I make tornado web return 403 if current_user is None instead of redirect to login_url?

Tags: authentication, tornado, http-status-code-403

Following is the implementation of method authenticated:

```
def authenticated(
        method: Callable[..., Optional[Awaitable[None]]]
    ) -> Callable[..., Optional[Awaitable[None]]]:
        """Decorate methods with this to require that the user be logged in.

        If the user is not logged in, they will be redirected to the configured
        `login url <RequestHandler.get_login_url>`.

        If you configure a login url with a query parameter, Tornado will
        assume you know what you're doing and use it as-is.  If not, it
        will add a `next` parameter so the login page knows where to send
        you once you're logged in.
        """

        @functools.wraps(method)
        def wrapper(  # type: ignore
            self: RequestHandler, *args, **kwargs
        ) -> Optional[Awaitable[None]]:
            if not self.current_user:
                if self.request.method in ("GET", "HEAD"):
                    url = self.get_login_url()
                    if "?" not in url:
                        if urllib.parse.urlsplit(url).scheme:
                            # if login url is absolute, make next absolute too
                            next_url = self.request.full_url()
                        else:
                            assert self.request.uri is not None
                            next_url = self.request.uri
                        url += "?" + urlencode(dict(next=next_url))
                    self.redirect(url)
                    return None
                raise HTTPError(403)
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
```

Seems there is no way to achieve what I want. When http method is GET, and if user didn't login, tornado will always redirect to login_url instead of just return 403.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the logic of getting user in your Base Handler

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    
    def get_current_user(self) -> Any:
        """Override to determine the current user from, e.g., a cookie.

        This method may not be a coroutine.
        """
        user = self.your_func_of_getting_user()
        if user is None:
            raise HTTPError(403)
        return user
```

for `async` purposes you can do the next:

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    _current_user: 'SomeUserModel | None' = None
    ...
    
    async def prepare(self):
        self._current_user = await self.your_async_func()
        if self._current_user is None:
            raise HTTPError(403)
```

Comment: Hi SimfikDuke, thank you for your reply. The problem with this solution is that, I am using asyio, I need to get user in an async function.

Comment: In this case you can prepare some data that should be extracted asynchronously in `prepare` method.

Comment: @timewalker I've updated an answer with `async` interface

Comment: @SimfikDuke It's a good answer, but you should write `self.current_user` instead of `self._current_user` as stated in the docs: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.current_user